# Amazon S3 object event creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

my AWS S3 bucket is associated with a Lambda function. Lambda is triggered by file insertion with certain file name. There is a XML file inside the same bucket from which lambda function reads the setting. The problem I am facing is that, when ever the settings file is not present/settings in the XML is wrong, the lambda launch will fail. But when the settings are made correct, lambda will get triggered for old files as well, where lambda got failed previously. I don't want trigger the Lambda again, once its failed for same file. Can some one direct me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the docs here:

http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

Lambda will attempt to execute your event at least 3 times before it gives up.

If you can handle the errors in your function (related to reading the config file), so that the Lambda Function exists with out error, then Lambda will not (normally) run your function again.